# How does a type satisfy the required signature for performing a map operation?

Tags: f#

**Can someone explain to me how the following line compiles?**

```
[1 .. 10] |> List.map string
```

**I expected the following function signature to be in the place of the string.**

('T -> 'U) -> 'T list -> 'U list

**I read the above signature as the following:**

List.map takes a function as input (i.e. ('T -> 'U) ) and yields another function as output (i.e. 'T list -> 'U list).

So how does the type "string" satisfy the required signature for performing a map operation?

NOTE:

I am two months into my journey of learning F#. Also note that I am a LOB developer and NOT a computer scientist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, string is a function like obj.ToString()

```
let f = string
// FSI:
// val f : (obj -> string)
```

The string signature is defined as

```
string : ^T -> string
```

where ^T is a statically resolved (compile-time generic) type parameter.

Comment: It's actually generic, not `obj ->`.

Answer (score 3):

In Core.Operators (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754.aspx) you have several conversion functions defined.  One is:

```
string : ^T -> string
```

You can call it with an explicit lambda

```
[1 .. 10] |> List.map (fun i -> string i)
```

Notice that the lambda `fun i -> string i` is a function of type `int -> string` so we can omit the lambda and refer to the function directly.

```
[1 .. 10] |> List.map (string)
```